is $\int_0^t \int_0^s \delta(u - v) \, du \, dv = \min(t, s) $?
Is the following integral equation true?
$
\int_0^t \int_0^s \delta(u - v) \, du \, dv = \min(t, s)
$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

thank you so much Sir! can you just tell me if the Dirac Delta function is considered as a function or not ? @MH.Lee

It is not a function, but close to it. The Dirac delta belongs to what is called generalized functions (or more commonly known as (Schwartz) distributions). Just like a function $f(x)$ can be regarded as an object representing the density of amount $f(x),\mathrm{d}x$ sitting on each infinitesimal interval of length $\mathrm{d}x$, a generalization function signifies localized quantity near each $x$. (For example, the Dirac delta is a unit mass concentrated about the origin.)
